# Xamarin form carouselview scrolls with multiple items for single scroll

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, carousel, maui

Iam using Carousel view control available in Xamarin form(Version 5).
In my case i used Listviews inside carousel view. It works fine if scroll by swiping to left or right, but if i programmatically set the ScrollTo or Position property for the carousel view using button click then it is scrolling multiple times though i'm setting single incremental value.

I added SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/scrolling#snap-points)

One more issue is if my current carousel position is zero and moving to last position or more then one is not working.

```
<AbsoluteLayout Margin="2" BackgroundColor="Transparent"> 
                <CarouselView 
                 x:Name="MyCarousalView"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                 Scrolled="CarouselViewScrolled">
                        <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="0" SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"  />
                        </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                  <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                        <ListView
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding .}"  
                        x:FieldModifier="public">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ViewCell Tapped="ViewCellTapped">
                                                <StackLayout Padding="0">
                                                    <StackLayout Padding="20,1" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Spacing="0" >
                                                        <Label
                                                        FontSize="16"    
                                                        Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                                        FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                        <Label
                                                        FontSize="14"   
                                                        Text="{Binding CreatedDate}"     />
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0" HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="#D4D4D4"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </ViewCell>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CarouselView> 
                </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Next button click event

```
private void NextClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            MyCarousalView.ScrollTo((MyCarousalView.Position + 1) < _weekDaysList.Count ? MyCarousalView.Position + 1 : 0);
        }
```

Carousel view binding:

```
  List<List<Note>> _myList;
    _myList=getData(); //based on service response
     MyCarousalView.ItemsSource = null;
    MyCarousalView.ItemsSource = _myList;
```

[Screen recording with issue image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15ikcFA39CFKBd3UNS25UkSAAZyolo6_y/view?usp=sharing)

[Screen video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OheR0-23MUHcvjCoz28Ysx17mJN6EfmX/view?usp=sharing)

Please letme know if any solution/workaround. Thanks

Comment: I did a test based on the code you posted, but I couldn't reproduce this problem. Could you please post a basic demo to github or driver so that we can test on ourside?In addition, you can recheck the code of function `CarouselViewScrolled`.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I will create and share

Comment: Waitting for your demo.

Comment: In my sample project it was working fine.  Skipping issue was resolved after removing two time binding carousel view. for zero to last position issue i added workaround like updating the position inside for loop one by one.  @JessieZhang-MSFT

Comment: Congrats. And thanks for your support for xamarin.